# regex and cut off the first part of the url(bootstrap active class remove from navbar element)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need some regex action.
It should cut off the ip part and look for the string after the "/".

**www.IdontCareForThisPart/ButForThisIDoCare/ThanInsertWildcardHere**

```
 $(function() {
     var url = document.URL.match(""); /* your awesome  regex here! */
     switch(url) {
         case "/Kalender":
             $('.cal').addClass("active");
             break;
         case "/Klienten":
             $('#asdf').addClass("active");
             break;
         case "/Aufgaben":
             $('.aufgaben').addClass("active");
             break;
         case "/Verwaltung":
             $('#verwaltung').addClass("active");
             break;
         case "/Willkommen":
             $('.nav > li:nth-child(1)').addClass("active");
             break;
         default:
             $('.nav > .active').removeClass();
             break;
     }
 });
```

Thank you for your time.
**Notes:**
I have changed the title of the question, now people who got the same problem can copy/paste this code.

Comment: I think you'd actually want to use location.pathname
Alternately, if you only want the first directory, you could use location.pathname.split('/')[1] and have your switch cases be without the leading slashes.

Comment: thank you @kevin.groat I tried it, it didn't work out for me.

Comment: @kevin.groat Could you please create an answer so I can accept it. your comment lead me to the correct way so I was able so solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

www.IdontCareForThisPart/ButForThisIDoCare/ANDthisToo

regex:

```
[^/]*/(.*)
```

[^/] means NOT SLASH, * means 0 or more times
The ( ) then capture what you want.  On the inside of the ( ) is . which means ANYTHING.

finally, if you are using / as your regex delimiter, you will have to escape the slashes:

```
/[^\/]*\/(.*)/
```

So the exact code you need to add is

```
url = url.replace(/[^\/]/,"")
```

This finds all the "not slashes" until it runs into a slash.  All that found stuff is replaced with "" (nothing).

Comment: thank you for that. I'm awful with this could you please insert it into my variable var url = yourregex

Comment: I edited my answer.  Please accept the answer and/or upvote it if you find it helpful.

Comment: kevin_groat helped me to solve the problem, he is not responding to my comment. But because of the way I asked the question it's only fair to accept your answer. I asked for regex you delivered. Thank you for your time. answer accepted

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expressions, just create an anchor linking the url, and get its `pathName`:

```
var a = document.createElement('a')
a.href = url;
a.pathName;
```

Or, in your case, if you want the path name of the current url, just use

```
location.pathname
```

The full code is

```
var selector = {
    "/Kalender": '.cal',
    "/Klienten": '#asdf',
    "/Aufgaben": '.aufgaben',
    "/Verwaltung": '#verwaltung',
    "/Willkommen": '.nav > li:nth-child(1)'
}[location.pathname];
$(selector || '.nav > .active').toggleClass("active", !!selector);
```

Comment: @user3447501 Which browser?

Comment: firefox also tested on chrome

Comment: @Oriol - for **'.nav > .active'**, he is removing a class, not adding "active".  Did you make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

For completeness here is the code which parses the first string after a the "/".

```
var url = window.location.pathname.split("/");
console.log(url[1]);
```